# JAXB REST PUT'ting referenced association

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rest, jaxb, jersey

Consider the following entity classes:

- `Manufacturer`: represents a car manufacturer (Ford, Volvo, ...) and has a name.
- `Model`: represents a model (Fiesta, S80), has a name, and is manufactured by a single manufacturer.

The manufacturer field in the model is annotated as follows:

```
@ManyToOne
@XmlIDREF
private Manufacturer manufacturer;
```

I then have two REST resources defined for getting and putting both manufacturers and types. The problem is with putting types:

```
@PUT
@Consumes("application/xml")
public void putModel(JAXBElement<Model> model) {
    modelFacade.create(model.getValue());
}
```

and the XML I try to put:

```
<model>
    <name>Fiesta</name>
    <manufacturer>1</manufacturer>
</model>
```

The manufacturer element points to `1`, a valid instance of `Manufacturer`, however, when the Model is persisted, the `MANUFACTURER_ID` is `null`. How can I get JAXB to read the manufacturer's ID from the XML as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider adding a hyperlink to the manufacturer instead of an ID (to make it more RESTful). See [this e-mail](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Sample-for-URI-lt-gt-JAXB-replacement-on-the-fly-td6185897.html) from the users@jersey mailing list which has an example of that.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Using both posts as a helping hand I was able to get this properly working, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following answer I gave to a similar question may help.  It makes use of an `XmlAdapter` to convert the referenced object to/from an ID:

- [Serialize a JAXB object via its ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278406/serialize-a-jaxb-object-via-its-id/7285517#7285517)

To leverage this in a JAX-RS environment to create a RESTful service you will need to leverage a MessageBodyReader in order to set an instance of EntityManager on the `XmlAdapter` passed to the `Unmarshaller`.