# Unmarshalling JAXB collection when using IDResolver failing because IDResolver Object as target type

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf

I have this problem trying to unmarshall json from rest webservice (cxf).
I'm using JAXB and EclipseLink.

The entity is mapped like that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "service_pkg_service", schema = "MD")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ServicePkgService extends DatabaseModel implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Transient
    @XmlIDREF
    private Set<ChannelPkgService> channelPkgServices = new HashSet<ChannelPkgService>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "channel_pkg_service", schema = "MD")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class ChannelPkgService extends DatabaseModel  implements java.io.Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "CHANNEL_PKG_ID")
    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

}
```

I have a class extending IDResolver, so I can generate an entity based on its ID.

```
public class EntityIDResolver extends IDResolver{

@Override
public void bind(String id, Object obj) throws SAXException {
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
@Override
public Callable<?> resolve(final String id, Class targetType) throws SAXException {

    }
}
```

I have problem unmarshalling json like this "channelPkgService": [1,2,3], the class of targetType is java.lang.Object

I read this https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/546 , and created a wrapper to handle this.

```
public class ChannelPkgServiceWrapper extends HashSet<ChannelPkgService>{
}
```

Sinse I have a lot of these cases and I don't want to create a lot of wrappers, is there a  more generic way to handle that?

Forget the used versions:

- cxf.version:2.3.6
- eclipselink:2.3.0
- jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar
  (jar containing Lister.class that is doing the actual work for getting the correct type.)

Answer (score 1):

`@XmlIDREF` is used by JAXB to map intra-document references.  Each object referenced by ID must also appear nested somewhere in the XML or JSON document:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

If you are looking to marshal an object as its ID, then you will want to use an `XmlAdapter`.  Check out my answer to a similar question:

- [Serialize a JAXB object via its ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278406/serialize-a-jaxb-object-via-its-id/7285517#7285517)

Also note that JAXB is a specification ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)), and [**EclipseLink**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink) contains the [**MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) implementation (I'm the MOXy tech lead).  This means you could eliminate jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar from your dependencies:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html